# Threads: How to put a check inside Thread Consumer for Data reciving check

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this producer Consumer sample Program shown below

How can i put  a Condition inside my Consumer Thread class  so that if i didn't recivied the data from producer for 1 minute ,  i  need to log that ??

This is my Producer Consumer Program

```
public class ProducerConsumerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CubbyHole c = new CubbyHole();
        Producer p1 = new Producer(c, 1);
        Consumer c1 = new Consumer(c, 1);
        p1.start();
        c1.start();
    }
}

class CubbyHole {
    private int contents;
    private boolean available = false;

    public synchronized int get() {
        while (available == false) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        available = false;
        notifyAll();
        return contents;
    }

    public synchronized void put(int value) {
        while (available == true) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        contents = value;
        available = true;
        notifyAll();
    }
}



class Producer extends Thread {
    private CubbyHole cubbyhole;
    private int number;

    public Producer(CubbyHole c, int number) {
        cubbyhole = c;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true)
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            cubbyhole.put(i);
            System.out.println("Producer #" + this.number + " put: " + i);
            try {
                sleep((int) (Math.random() * 2000));
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        }
    }
}


class Consumer extends Thread {
    private CubbyHole cubbyhole;
    private int number;

    public Consumer(CubbyHole c, int number) {
        cubbyhole = c;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true)
        {
        int value = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            value = cubbyhole.get();
            System.out.println("Consumer #" + this.number + " got: " + value);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Could anybody please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Object#wait(long timeout)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29) and log from inside the `get()` method:

```
try {
    wait(60 * 1000);
    if (available == false) {
        //log
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks Keepil , but how can this work , because i guess it willl wait for 1 minute every time know ??

My requirement is that if data isn't recievied from producer until 1 minute log that

Comment: This will log a message every minute while waiting. If you only want to log after the first minute, you can add a boolean to make sure it only happens once.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`System.currentTimeMilis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) in your `Consumer run` method`:`

```
long before;
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        before = System.currentTimeMilis();
        value = cubbyhole.get();
        if (System.currentTimeMilis() - before > 1000 * 60) {
            System.out.println("Consumer waited for more than one minute");
        }
        System.out.println("Consumer #" + this.number + " got: " + value);
}
```